# Using webHDFS through Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, webhdfs

how can I acces webHDFS using spark.

Problem Statement : "Need to get the files from local system to HDFS and then process it in Spark. Want to skip SFTP."

Comment: Can you elaborate more the question?

Comment: I need to copy files from local system to hadoop and process it in spark...I want this whole process to be done in spark only and need to use webhdfs for that.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a sparkContext:

```
 val rdd : RDD[String] = sparkContext.textFile(path)
 rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://[url:path]")
```

Note that your Spark executor must access to your 'local' file system